# How can I access my static variable from other page? Enqueue / Dequeue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm enqueuing the incoming customer in my KioskController.

```
public ActionResult SetQueueInfo([Bind(Include = "QueueId,Name,QueueNumber,ServiceId,ServiceName,ServiceLetter")] Queue queue/*, int? id,string Name, string QueueNumber, string ServiceLetter, int ServiceId*/, int? id)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        MyQueue.todayQueue.Enqueue(queue);
        db.Queues.Add(queue);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View(queue);
    }

    return View();
}
```

I want to Dequeue it on my TellerScreenController how can I use the static variable to Dequeue it,

Here is my TellerScreenController:

```
    public ActionResult BtnNext()
    {
        var first = MyQueue.todayQueue.Dequeue();

        TempData["QueueItem"] = first;

        return View();
    }
```

Here is my Queue Class:

```
public class MyQueue
{
    public int MyQueueId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string QueueNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0}{1:000}", ServiceLetter ?? "?", QueueId);
        }
        set { }
    }

    public static Queue<MyQueue> todayQueue = new Queue<MyQueue>();

    public string ServiceLetter { get; set; }

    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class for TodayQueue

```
public class QueueHelper{
     public static Queue<Queue> TodayQueue = new Queue<Queue>();
}
```

In Kios controller

```
public ActionResult SetQueueInfo([Bind(Include = "QueueId,Name,QueueNumber,ServiceId,ServiceName,ServiceLetter")] Queue queue/*, int? id,string Name, string QueueNumber, string ServiceLetter, int ServiceId*/, int? id)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        QueueHelper.TodayQueue.Enqueue(queue);
        db.Queues.Add(queue);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View(queue);
    }

    return View();
}
```

In Teller screen

```
  public ActionResult BtnFinish()
    {
        var first = QueueHelper.TodayQueue.Dequeue();

        TempData["QueueItem"] = first;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

In Index cshtml view

```
@{
   var item = (MyQueue)TempData["QueueItem"];
}

<p>@item.Name</p>
```

Comment: I have a class named Queue where I store the incoming customers Name, ID, QueueNumber

Comment: HI @Hien Nguyen, do you have an idea of how can I able to display the dequeued data on my page?

Comment: in my tempdata im getting the data of my dequeued object, how can i get it to show on my view forexample the QueueNumber of the customer

Comment: that only example, you can use properties from TempData

Comment: I'cant see the properties i dunno why. but my tempdata is getting it

Comment: Using the generic type 'Queue<T>' requires 1 type arguments thats the error

Comment: Change to (Queue<Queue>)TempData please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193307/discussion-between-hien-nguyen-and-carlo-toribio).

Comment: Can you change the name Queue to MyQueue please? It is not easy recognize what is system class and your class

Comment: still not working. 
Error message: The type or Namespace name 'MyQueue' could not be found(are you missing  a using directive  or an assembly reference?)